# Is this the correct way to obtain the access token

Tags: c#, access-token, http-status-code-403, yahoo-api

I managed to get the request token but I cant get the access token. Is my way of getting the access token correct. Any suggestions ?

```
 //Step : 1 (Returns Request Token)
string consumer_key = "dj0yJmk9bl..........lRReU9UWXkmcz1jb25zdW1lcnNlY3JldCZ4PWIy";
string username = "some_user";
string pass = "some_pass";
string url = "https://login.yahoo.com/WSLogin/V1/get_auth_token?&login="+username+"&passwd="+pass+"&oauth_consumer_key="+consumer_key;

HttpWebRequest request_a = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
Stream objStream;
objStream = request_a.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
StreamReader objReader = new StreamReader(objStream);
string resp = objReader.ReadLine(); //Since first line has the response - "Returns RequestToken=jUO3Qolu3AYGU1KtB9vUbxlnzfIiFRLP.."
string requesttoken = resp.Replace("RequestToken=", "");

//Step : 2 (Returns OAuth access token)
string auth_ = "&Authorization=OAuth";
string realm = "&realm=yahooapis.com";
string oauth_consumer_key = "&oauth_consumer_key=dj0yJmk9....bzlNVEV4TlRReU9UWXkmcz1jb25zdW1lcnNlY3JldCZ4PWIy"; //This is Consumer Key
string oauth_nonce = "&oauth_nonce=24829.2331";
string oauth_signature_method = "&oauth_signature_method=PLAINTEXT";
string tstamp = "&oauth_timestamp=1219450170";
string oauth_token = "&oauth_token="+ requesttoken; //
string oauth_version = "&oauth_version=1.0";
string oauth_signat = "&oauth_signature=cbbe4eacb0c171ee9a78c070d2095a86dcc2b6ba"; // This is the Consumer Secret
string new_url = "https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth/v2/get_token?";
string command = new_url + auth_ + realm + oauth_consumer_key + oauth_nonce + oauth_signature_method + tstamp + oauth_token + oauth_version + oauth_signat;

HttpWebRequest request_b = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(command);
Stream objStream_b;
objStream_b = request_a.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
StreamReader objReader_b = new StreamReader(objStream);
```

I tried testing the command variable in the webbrowser and i get the following

> Sorry, Forbidden: You don't have permission to access this URL on this server.

Please check the URL for proper spelling and capitalization. If you're having trouble locating a destination on Yahoo!, try visiting the Yahoo! home page or look through a list of Yahoo!'s online services. Also, you may find what you're looking for if you try searching below.

Comment: You're missing `using` statements and `try-catch` blocks.

Answer (score 0):

There's no `&` in the beginning of oauth_signat...and I don't know about yahoo api but should this `string auth_ = "&Authorization: OAuth";` be this `string auth_ = "&Authorization=OAuth";`

Comment: I just added the & but I am still getting that error. Also changed the : to =